# How to view images in django html template

Tags: python, django, image, static, http-status-code-404

I keep getting 404 error even though the url to the image is accurate. Yes, I have looked at official django docs and a whole lot of stackoverflow posts. I couldn't figure it out from those. If anyone can decipher what the [instructions are saying](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/) to do then I will be grateful because they seem to be missing information.

index.html:

```
#I have tried static and staticfiles
{% load static %}
#a lot of code later...
<img border="0" src="{% static "logo.png" %}" alt="TMS" width="125" height="80">
```

Directory structure:

```
projectname
    ->__init__.py, settings.py, ...
manage.py
db.sql3
app_name
    -> admin.py, models.py, views.py, templates->index.html, ...
static
    ->logo.png
```

The only thing about static that I have in settings.py along with 'django.contrib.staticfiles':

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My views.py file has index function which returns HttpResponse(t.render(c)) where t is the index.html template and c is Context. Could those be the issue?

The url that results is this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/logo.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a static directory which is outside of your app (it is in the project folder), so in settings.py you need also:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: and use `{% load staticfiles %}` in your template

Comment: Holy crap it worked. Man you have no idea how much stress this was causing me. Oddly I did add that code in at some point but for some reason it has worked now. Thank you.